# Is using Ethereum to trade in betting markets legal in US?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bitcoin, augur

Right now the betting market in US is regulated by CFTC and some sites like PredictIt have $850 limit per contract to be compliant with CFTC.

I have seen some  prediction markets like Augur that use Ethereum for betting. Is it legal for betting in US using Ethereum ?